# React divide string over multiple input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have four `input` fields for a 16 digit voucher code (`xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx`)

It's possible to manually input the code in the fields, separately but I also want people to just copy/paste the code so it will automatically fill in all input fields.

I have read some solutions but nothing was `React` specific

The inputs are loaded dynamically from an `Object`

```
render() {
  return this.fieldNames.map((fieldName, index) => (
    <div className="col-md-3">
      <input
        className="voucher-field"
        maxLength="4"
        onChange={this.onChange}
        ref={(item) => { this.fields[fieldName] = item; }}
      />
    </div>
  ));
}

function onChange() {
  const { value } = event.target;
  console.log(value);
}
```

I assume that when you paste, it will trigger the `onChange()` function but when I do, the value logged is only 4 characters long (max limit input).

How can I divide my copied string over the inputs?

Comment: Please provide minimal, working example or use codesandbox :)

Comment: @Kinduser: codesandbox is off-site. Examples should be **on-site**, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Be serious. Making a working example in code snippet requires much more effort than setting it up on codesandbox. People are lazy, don't you know? :)

Comment: Greg, there are several bugs in the code above which should be resolved prior to posting a question. But fundamentally: You'll have to remove the `maxLength` if you want to allow people to paste into (say) the first field and then handle spreading it across fields for them. Both `input` and `change` will only give you the truncated text.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I'm trying to set up an example in the meantime